# User failed to be authenticated in WebLogic

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic11g, weblogic12c

I'm having problem with authenticating my weblogic server, i assigned correct username and password, what went wrong with my project? Is there any configuration that i need to be configure with my web logic server that causes this error  authentication and what it would be? I already added wlfullclient.jar file.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.AuthenticationException [Root exception is java.lang.SecurityException: User: webogic, failed to be authenticated.]
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ExceptionTranslator.toNamingException(ExceptionTranslator.java:42)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.toNamingException(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:808)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.pushSubject(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:697)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.newContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:485)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:373)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:319)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:288)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.rest.client.Type4Conn.main(Type4Conn.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: User: webogic, failed to be authenticated.
    at weblogic.common.internal.RMIBootServiceImpl.authenticate(RMIBootServiceImpl.java:116)
    at weblogic.common.internal.RMIBootServiceImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:693)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:519)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:515)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
```

Here is my code:

```
 public static void main(String ar[])throws Exception{
        String username="weblogic";
        String password="weblogic";

        Properties p=new Properties();
        p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"t3://192.168.1.188:7001");        
        p.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);        
        p.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);        
        InitialContext ctx=new InitialContext(p);
        DataSource ds=(DataSource)ctx.lookup("ds_orclmrcos");    
        System.out.println(ds);
        Connection con=ds.getConnection();
        Statement st=con.createStatement();

        st.executeUpdate("insert into TBL_CUSTOMER(CUST_ID, CUST_FNAME, CUST_MNAME, CUST_LNAME,CUST_ADDRESS,CUST_STATUS)"+
        "VALUES('C-002', 'ALVIN', 'C.','TEST','MANILA', 'PERMANENT')");

        System.out.println(" records inserted");


    }
```

Comment: How are you attempting to connect? How are you providing the credentials? What does your code look like in `com.rest.client.Type4Conn`?

Comment: here is my code, i updated my post.

Comment: Is your username really _webogic_? Should it be _weblogic_?

Comment: thats just an typo error in my post coz i edited it.. but same error happened in accessing my web logic server with right username and password...

Comment: what jar file should i need to add to my build path weblogic.jar, wlclient.jar, weblogic.jar file those three was imported to my project, am i doing right?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having this problem in IntelliJ, when you go to your WebLogic server configurations you might notice that the password field is blank. I solved this problem by entering the password, saving and then restarting the server. For some reason, IntelliJ loses the password to WebLogic. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

May you have lock your user account.. Try to unlock it : 
In WLS Console (you need to be log as admin)
 -> Security -> Unlock User
Type your user to unlock here.

Answer (score 1):

I also had similar problem and guess what while installing..the previous attempt I had `put password not satisfying the criteria` but don't know why even if the script exited a process was running in background, after killing that process issue resolved. :D

Answer (score 1):

1. Access the weblogic console.
2. Open the security realms.
3. In the Users And Groups tab create a user.
4. In your code use the same username and password.

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic11g and 12c require passwords to include number or symbols - "[Security:099116]**The number of numeric or special characters in a password can not be less than 1**." - so I think your password 'weblogic' is not going to work.

You can goto WebLogic Admin Console to reset the password: Admin Console >> Security Realms >> myrealm >> Users and Groups >> weblogic >> Passwords.

EDIT:
It works on my machine! And I hit below similar exception stack if I provide a wrong password:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: User: weblogic, failed to be authenticated.
at weblogic.common.internal.RMIBootServiceImpl.authenticate(RMIBootServiceImpl.java:116)
at weblogic.common.internal.RMIBootServiceImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

I used the same code as yours, and wlfullclient.jar (interesting though, it is from my DB installation folder: 11.2.0.3/dbhome_1/owb/lib/int/wlfullclient.jar).

Comment: i see. okay things goes right. but this is my problem: Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.NO_PERMISSION:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No

Comment: things goes weird, i edited my username and password but same thing happened.

Comment: I re-enter the use name and password and tested the connection, it is working fine.